# Onclick or click function don't work inside bxSlider with touchEnabled: true

Tags: jquery, bxslider

The onlick function inside a bxSlider don't work.

I've tried to use

```
$(".mybutton").on('click', function() { console.log('Hello word')});
```

tried to use `onlick="trythis()` but nothing work.

HTML CODE

```
<ul class="productSlider">
    <li>Image 1 <div class="mybutton">click me</div></li>
    <li>Image 2 <div class="mybutton">click me</div></li>
    <li>Image 3 <div class="mybutton">click me</div></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY SLIDER CODE

```
var  mySlider =  $('.productSlider').bxSlider({
    pager:false,
    controls:false,
    autoplay:true,
    shrinkItems:true,
    slideMargin:10,
    touchEnabled: true,
});
mySlider.reloadSlider();
```

JQUERY ON CLICK

```
$('.mybutton').on('click', function(){
    console.log('Hello Word');
})
```

When i click on div with class mybutton nothing happens. If i set touchEnabled: false, all work fine.

Thanks

Comment: Is inside the footer.php inside document.ready

Comment: bxSlider could be stopping events on interior elements.

Comment: if i add touchEnabled: false, all work fine. but i need touchEnable: true...

Comment: I updated the question, hope someone can help me... Unfortunally isn't my site and is first time with bxSlider

Comment: You might have to switch sliders. Flickity is good. I use click events on images with it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the **click** event I suggest to use **mousedown**:

```js
var  mySlider =  $('.productSlider').bxSlider({
    pager:false,
    controls:false,
    autoplay:true,
    shrinkItems:true,
    slideMargin:10,
    touchEnabled: true,
});
mySlider.reloadSlider();
$('.mybutton').on('mousedown', function(){
    console.log('Hello Word');
})
```

```css
.mybutton {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#444;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background:#DDD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<ul class="productSlider">
    <li>Image 1 <div class="mybutton">click me</div></li>
    <li>Image 2 <div class="mybutton">click me</div></li>
    <li>Image 3 <div class="mybutton">click me</div></li>
</ul>
```